# With octokit.rb (Ruby library for GitHub API) how do you set Accept: header in post request (for API Previews)?

Tags: ruby, github, graphql, octokit

When using Octokit to do post request to the graphql endpoint, how do you set custom `Accept:` headers in order to turn on a "preview" API?

I need to do a GraphQL query that is part of an API preview, so it requires me to set the `Accept` header to `application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json` (see [GitHub API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/schema-previews#create-content-attachments-preview)).

I am using Octokit (4.15.0) in a Rails project, and am successfully doing normal queries (not preview mode) using both the v3 and v4 (GraphQL) APIs.

For normal queries (not API preview), my code looks like this, and works flawlessly.  Here, the method `graphql_query_string` forms the correct query string, and `github_machine_user` is an instance of an Octokit `Client` object.

Code that works (when custom `Accept:` header not needed)

```rb
   def perform_graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after="")
      graphql_query_string = graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after)
      options = { query: graphql_query_string }.to_json
      github_machine_user.post '/graphql', options
    end
```

This results in the default `Accept` header being used, which is, apparently `"application/vnd.github.v3+json"` (more on how I know this below.)

I tried several ways of adding a custom `Accept:` header, but none of them work. Here's what I tried:

Unsuccessful Attempt #1:

```rb
  def perform_graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after="")
      graphql_query_string = graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after)
      options = {:query => graphql_query_string, 
        :headers => {:accept => "application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json"}
      }.to_json
      github_machine_user.post('/graphql', options)
      
    end
```

Unsuccessful Attempt #2:

```rb
   def perform_graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after="")
      graphql_query_string = graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after)
      options = {
          :query => graphql_query_string, 
          :accept => "application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json"
      }.to_json
      github_machine_user.post('/graphql', options)
    end
```

Neither of theses sets the proper header.  From the source code for the [post](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/dbea2c6c72637965f75517c006cea0870c920798/lib/octokit/connection.rb#L27) method and the underlying [request](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/dbea2c6c72637965f75517c006cea0870c920798/lib/octokit/connection.rb#L147) method, I would have expected this to work.   Here's what those look like.

```rb
    # Make a HTTP POST request
    #
    # @param url [String] The path, relative to {#api_endpoint}
    # @param options [Hash] Body and header params for request
    # @return [Sawyer::Resource]
    def post(url, options = {})
      request :post, url, options
    end
```

```rb
     def request(method, path, data, options = {})
      if data.is_a?(Hash)
        options[:query]   = data.delete(:query) || {}
        options[:headers] = data.delete(:headers) || {}
        if accept = data.delete(:accept)
          options[:headers][:accept] = accept
        end
      end
```

Is it me, or a bug in Octokit?

I can tell the header isn't being set not just because I get results indicating `Field 'project' doesn't exist on type 'AddedToProjectEvent'`, because I also followed the [advice in the Octokit documentation about turning on debugging info](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/#Debugging) and I can see the headers on my request.

Here's how they appear (other than the redacted credential)

```
I, [2020-07-24T12:26:37.989030 #64350]  INFO -- request: POST https://api.github.com/graphql
I, [2020-07-24T12:26:37.989109 #64350]  INFO -- request: Accept: "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
User-Agent: "Octokit Ruby Gem 4.15.0"
Content-Type: "application/json"
Authorization: "token REDACTED_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW_POST"
```

So my requests to set the accept header are not being respected.

I did verify that using `curl`, I was able to get the query to work properly by passing the correct `Accept` header.  So the graphQl query is properly formed, and when the Accept header is properly put into the query, everything is fine. But I just can't seem to figure out how to get Octokit to respect my wishes in setting the Accept header.  I've even looked into the source, and it *seems* like what I'm doing should work.

Can anyone help?

Update: Posted as an [issue on Octokit's GitHub Repo](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/1274) too.

Update #2:  I tried removing the `to_json`.  Unfortunately, that gives a stack trace as shown below.

If I remove the `to_json` and then *only* pass the `{:accept => "application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json"}` then it *does* set the correct header.  But if try including `:query` in that hash, it results in the error below, unless I have the `to_json` on the hash.   I just can't seem to win.

```
NoMethodError undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00007fb05be10b00>
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/utils/params_hash.rb:28:in `update'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sawyer-0.8.2/lib/sawyer/agent.rb:99:in `block in call'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:489:in `block in run_request'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:506:in `block in build_request'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/request.rb:55:in `block in create'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/request.rb:54:in `tap'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/request.rb:54:in `create'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:502:in `build_request'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:484:in `run_request'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/faraday-1.0.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:279:in `post'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/sawyer-0.8.2/lib/sawyer/agent.rb:94:in `call'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/octokit-4.18.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:156:in `request'
/Users/pconrad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/octokit-4.18.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:28:in `post'
/Users/pconrad/github/project-anacapa/anacapa-github-linker/app/jobs/course/course_github_repo_get_sdlc_events.rb:105:in `perform_graphql_query'
```

Update #3: Added [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093826/13960329) but it seems hacky.  I had to call a private method, which one is not supposed to do, and definitely not supposed to "have to do".  So, still hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/910#issuecomment-643292500 I assume you want [`Octokit::Preview::PREVIEW_TYPES[:project_card_events]`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/octokit/Octokit/Preview)

Comment: That's helpful in the sense that 


`Octokit::Preview::PREVIEW_TYPES[:project_card_events]`


is an alias for: `"application/vnd.github.starfox-preview+json"`

The question remains: how to pass that to Client.post

Passing:  `:accept => Octokit::Preview::PREVIEW_TYPES[:project_card_events]` in the `options` hash is what the API docs suggest.  But that doesn't have any effect on the Accept param used in the post request.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked.  I had to get "dirty" and invoke a private method using `.send` which is not ideal.

```
graphql_query_string = graphql_query(repo_name, org_name, after).gsub("\n","")

data = {
    :query => graphql_query_string, 
}.to_json
options = {
  :headers => {
  :accept => Octokit::Preview::PREVIEW_TYPES[:project_card_events]
  }
}
github_machine_user.send :request, :post, '/graphql', data,options
```

If there is a better way, I'd welcome the suggestion.  I agree with the other posters that said it doesn't make any sense to pass `to_json` on the data part, but without it, I get the stack trace about `each` not being defined on a string.

Comment: I don't think there's another way. The `query` parameter is too overloaded and there's a conflict in the API preventing sending a Hash with `query` that is being mistaken as the `query` in `options` passed to the HTTP agent. This should be reported in the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove calling `#to_json` on `options`. You're passing a String into `#post` as `options`. `options` gets put into `#request` as `data`. `#request` will do its thing on `data` if it was a `Hash` but since it's a String, it won't populate the new `options` that is passed to the client in `#request`.

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.  It totally makes sense.  But for some reason, when I do that, there is a stack dump from inside the internals of the `Client.post` method.    Adding `to_json` makes the query work (as long as I don't use any preview features.).

Comment: @PhillConrad what does the stack dump look like?

Comment: @PhillConrad you also may want to call #request directly and not rely on #request to populate the header value inside its options variable.

Comment: That way, data stays a string, but the client options can change like header.

Comment: I can't show you the stack dump in a comment, but I'll add it in the original post.

Comment: Oof, I didn't realize #request itself is private. Blargh. So much for calling it directly.

Comment: No, it was a valuable suggestion.  At least I have a workaround now.  See my own answer.  So Thanks!